# Apply active class to nav item whose href is set to id of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a variation of the bootstrap 3 collapse feature for a menu and I'm trying to apply an active style to the nav item whose contents are open and visible.

My thought is to hook into the 'panel-collapse" whose class is also set to "in" which is the class that gets applied to the active visible panel by using the id that the anchor tag href is set to in the nav.

I'm just having difficulty figuring out how to hook into the id of the active panel to apply an active class back to the correct nav item.

```
    <nav>
      <div id="group-sub-nav-list">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-sub-menu" href="#vbs-programs-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-nav-menus" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="vbs-programs-menu">VBS Programs</a></li>
          <li><a href="/vbs/tools">Tools</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="sub-nav-menus" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" id="shop-vbs-menu"> </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" id="vbs-programs-menu"> </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a class, and would like to use jQuery to change class on click use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-sub-menu').click(function(){
        ('.nav-sub-menu').toggleClass('panel-collapse')
    })

})
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to add/remove a class on the nav item that you click to show/hide its corresponding panel based on the id of the panel being used for the href on the nav item. This class that gets added should only be added to the nav item whose panel is active and removed when its corresponding panel is not active.

Comment: I found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343872/bootstrap-3-active-class-add-remove-on-button-outside-of-accordion-container

Comment: What is the id of this nav item? So you would like to make the nav class dependent on another panel's state? And would you like to make the class of the nav item dependent on the href as well?